# mongodbからデータを取り出してクラスタリングするプログラム

Tags: python, python3, twitter

http://www.inmyzakki.com/entry/2017/05/17/190000
上記のページのプログラムを自分の環境で走らせたいです。

実行すると以下の通りになります。

```
python gettweet.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gettweet.py", line 29, in <module>
    for tweet in data:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

自分のソースコードは以下の通りです。

```
#twitterAPIアクセス
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&lang=ja&q=" + word
auth = OAuth1(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
response = requests.get(url, auth = auth)
data = response.json().get('statuses')
```

データ表示

```
cnt = 0
while True:
    for tweet in data:
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(tweet["id"])#ツイートID
        print(tweet["text"])#ツイート内容
        print(tweet["created_at"])#ツイート日時
        cnt += 1
        maxid = int(tweet["id"]) - 1

    #ツイートがない場合ループ終了
    if len(data) == 0:
        break

    url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&lang=ja&q=" + word + "&max_id=" + str(maxid)
    auth = OAuth1(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    response = requests.get(url, auth = auth)
    data = response.json()['statuses']
    print("ツイート数:" + str(cnt))}
```

TrueがNonetype errorとのことだったので、ググったところnonetype errorはdef等の関数を指定した
際のエラーがでることはわかったのですが、Trueの場合の対処法がわかりませんでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ツイートがない場合のチェックをforループの前でやればOKですね。`if not data`でいけます。

Comment: if not data:breakをwhile True: の直後に追加したところエラーが出なくなりました。ありがとうございます。